# How to get a fluro past the lava pit?

Tags: vessel

I'm in the second stage of the Vessel demo. Here I need to get a fluro to the button with the green light on it to lower the yellow-red door. When I make one, the fluro jumps his merry way on the three platforms and evaportes on the second.

It seems that the three lava fountains are fed from the water drain on the left, but trying to suck water off the water source doesn't seem to be any effective. What can I do then?

[image]

I have tried placing fluro seeds to reduce the amount of lava the fluro must get through (see above) but it also seems uneffective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make a lava fluro instead of a water fluro!

Use the first kind of fluro (the one that likes buttons). Throw it in the lava and it will head for the button :-)

Comment: uh... is there such a thing as a lava fluro?!

Comment: Just throw a seed into the lava and see?

Comment: I was stuck here too, and only accidentally dropped a seed in the lava. :)